# Where should I put the estimate gas produced by the remix IDE in my code?

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, erc-20, ethereumjs

I'm creating the ERC20 smartcontract transfer with web3.

I just want to use gas optimally so that users want to do token transfer.

From the Remix IDE I got the GASESTIMATES.

But I don't know where to put this. Should I put on gas, gas price or gas limit?

I got an estimate for tokentransfer from Remix IDE is 46877.

So, where do I put this in the code?

```
// transfer params are _address and _amount
var parameterValues = [toAddress,transferAmount];

// I use this to get data for raw tx
var encodeAbi = web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall(oneAbiFunctionHere, parameterValues);

web3.eth.getTransactionCount(addressFrom).then(function(txCount){

  var theNonce  = web3.utils.toHex(txCount);

  var theTx = {
    to: qEnv.smartcontract_address,
    value: '0x0',
    gas: web3.utils.toHex(84000),               // should I put over here?
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(60000),          // or here?
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(168000000000),   // or here?
    nonce: theNonce,
    chainId: qEnv.web3ChainId,
    data: encodeAbi 
  };

  var tx = new EthereumTx(theTx, {chain: qEnv.web3ChainName});

  tx.sign(privateKey);

  var raw = '0x' + tx.serialize().toString('hex');

  web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw, function (err, transactionHash) {
    if(transactionHash) {
      callback('success', transactionHash)
    }
    else {
      callback('fail', 'Error transfer')
    }
  });
})
```

Please help.

Comment: What is `EthereumTx`? Is it `ethereumjs-tx`? In that case `gas` doesn't exist, and `gasPrice` is a price not a gas amount. I won't recommend to hardcode gas limit estimations since they depend on the contract's state. Unless the contract it is really simple it is better to estimate before sending and add a 5-10% extra just in case.

Comment: Hi @Ismael, thanks for your reply. Yes, `EthereumTx` from `ethereumjs-tx`. I can see from metamask, it doesn't include `gas` as well. So, I am going to remove it. And the important thing is I got GASESTIMATES from Remix IDE is `46877`. Is this `gasLimit` or `gasPrice`?

Comment: Gas estimation should go in `gasLimit`. The `gasPrice` for mainnet can be obtained from etherscan.io/gasTracker or ethgasstation.info.